# Deploying a pelican site to Google Cloud Run with Dockerfile not working

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, pelican

I have a website built with pelican site generator, and I would like to dockerize it and deploy it to GCP using Cloud Run. I'm not super familiar with docker and can't figure out what to use as my `ENTRYPOINT`. So far I have this in my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye AS pelican

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git \
  make \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# prevent writing .pyc files
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# bust the cache 
WORKDIR /website 
COPY . /website/

RUN pelican

FROM httpd:2.4.52-alpine
COPY --from=pelican /website/output/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

And when I build and run with `docker run -d -p 8080:80 website` my website is running alright at localhost:8080. However when I deploy this to GCP Cloud Run, I get this error

```
terminated: Application failed to start: failed to resolve binary path: error finding executable "docker run -d -p 8080:80 website" in PATH [/usr/local/apache2/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin]: no such file or directory
```

And I've put `docker run -d -p 8080:80 website` as my container arguments.

I've followed steps outlined here https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-push-docker-image for building the image, deploy it to Artifact Registry, but I wasn't able to run the image or deploy it to cloud run. There are also more generic error messages like

```
"efault STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "xx-image-1" on port 8080. The instance was not started.
```

Not sure how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks fine to me.  The `httpd` image already knows how to launch Apache HTTPD and you don't need to replace its `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT`).  The error suggests to me a quoting problem as you're deploying it to Google Cloud Run, and not necessarily something in your image.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you, I just updated my question and added more info on my deployment to Google Cloud Run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this!

In my Dockerfile, I exposed port 80 instead of 8080, and when I run it locally I have `docker run -d -p 8080:80 website`

So in the Cloud Run I should have used port 80, instead of the default 8080. I edited it here:
[image]

FYI I also need to enable upload to artifact registry with the following before I could upload the container from commandline.

```
gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
```